# Why is this for-in loop running on an empty array?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, loops, core-bluetooth

Some seriously weird stuff is going on here:

```
1    - (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverServices:(NSError *)error {
2        if (error) {
3            NSLog(@"Error discovering services: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
4            return;
5        }
6        for (CBService *service in peripheral.services) {
7            NSLog(@"found service");
8            if ([service.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"6D59"]]) { // SwitchaBLE UUID
9                [peripheral discoverCharacteristics:@[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"6D5A"], [CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"6D5B"], [CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"6D5C"]] forService:service];
10           }
11       }
12   }
```

1. I put a breakpoint at line 6. In the console, I can see that `peripheral.services` has zero objects.
2. Single step. Hits line 6 again.
3. Single step. Goes to line 11. Expected.
4. Single step. Goes to line 9. WHAAAAAA? Console: `print service` gives me: `error: use of undeclared identifier 'service'`.

What the heck just happened?

Comment: Did you compile with the Release configuration? In that case the compiler optimizes and rearranges code, and the "current position" shown in the debugger can be quite wrong.

Comment: Maybe look at the assembly to see if the compiler did some optimization that makes it look like there is out of order execution going on. It may shed some light as to what's actually happening. I know Xcode has a way to show the assembly (check the assistant editor..it may have options for showing the assembly).

Comment: Could it possibly be that one of the service objects in the loop is not of the expected kind or somehow nil? Try outputting details about the instance and its class before the if statement...

Comment: I don't see the use of characterstics property in your code - you mentioned it in 1.

Comment: @AlekseyKozhevnikov, that was a typo. Fixed it.

Comment: Please respond to @MartinR's question, unless you want to think about it for another day.

Comment: @MartinR, nope, it has been in build configuration the whole time. I ended up using `filteredArrayUsingBlock` and the problem (if it really was a problem) ceased.